# Zonal statistics

Tags: raster, zonal-statistics, statistics

I am using Python on Visual Code Studio. Basically, I have two raster images, GHS SMOD (which classifies areas into 8 catergories of urban) and GHS POP (which uses world pop to calculate population). I downloaded it from https://ghsl.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ and I clipped it to a country's shapefile using the different administrative units.

Now I need to calculate zonal statistics for each urbanization category (defined by smod_vals) within the administrative unit. However every time I do zonal statistics on Python, the error keeps coming. No matter what I do.

This is a snippet of the code:

```
for val in smod_vals:
            cur_smod = (smod_file == val).astype(int)
            smod = (smod_file == val)*pop_file
            cur_pop = pop_file * cur_smod
            total_curpop = cur_pop.sum()
            perUrban = (total_curpop.sum() / total_pop * 100)
        

            out_name = os.path.join(outdir, f"{year}_{iso3}_{val}_smod_pop.tif")
            print("out_name:", out_name)
        
            with rasterio.open(out_name, 'w', **out_meta) as out_urban:
                out_urban.write(cur_pop)
            
            # Zonal Statistics, reference: https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/geospatial-python/10-zonal-statistics/index.html
            smod_pop = rioxarray.open_rasterio(out_name).squeeze()

            fields_rasterized = features.rasterize(geom, out_shape=smod_pop.shape, transform=smod_pop.rio.transform())
            fields_rasterized_xarr = smod_pop.copy()
            fields_rasterized_xarr.data = fields_rasterized

            results= zonal_stats(fields_rasterized_xarr, smod_pop, stats_funcs=['sum'])
```

The issue is in the last line. I am lost.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: 1473     """
-> 1474     result = super().__getitem__(key)
   1475     # Custom logic to avoid waiting for pandas GH51895
   1476     # result is not geometry dtype for multi-indexes
...
-> 6175     raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   6177 not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
   6178 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")

KeyError: "None of [Index(['Shape_Area', 'ADM3_PCODE', 'ADM3_EN'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.